# Android ContentResolver.query() throwing exception when passing a String[] projection argument

Tags: android, sql, cursor

In my current Android project I'm facing with a strange error.

Everytime I issue the [query method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)) I get errors saying that the columns of the passed projection String[] argument don't exist (_id column field comprised). Despite this, **passing null** (hence allowing all columns to be returned) **works fine**, so I must assume this is not a problem of column names mismatch. Also, when retrieving data from a Cursor object, the column names are not giving any problems, since I can safely get all of the data by specifying the same column names on query().

I'm currently querying on the MediaStore.Audio.* database, and all the permissions within the Manifest file and eventual settings are ok.

This is my code snippet:

```
  Cursor        artists[] = new Cursor[2];

        String  projection[] = {
                Audio.Artists.ARTIST,
                Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_ALBUMS,
                Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_TRACKS,
        };

    artists[0] = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                    Audio.Artists.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    Audio.Artists.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
                    );

    artists[1] = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                    Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    Audio.Artists.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
                    );

            this.adapter = new ArtistListAdapter(this.getActivity(), new MergeCursor(artists));
```

Just to make it clear, here's where I use the Cursor object:

```
@Override
public void bindView (View v, Context c, Cursor cursor) {
    ImageView   icon;
    TextView    name, artistInfo;

    //icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.artist_icon);
    name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
    artistInfo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.artist_info);

    //icon.setIcon(icon);
    name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Artists.ARTIST)));
    artistInfo.setText(
            String.format(
                    "%s total albums\n%s total songs",
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_ALBUMS)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_TRACKS))
            )
    );
}
```

Issuing this code, I receive the following error:

```
07-11 21:28:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22737): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 21:28:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22737): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
07-11 21:28:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22737):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
07-11 21:28:31.221: E/AndroidRuntime(22737):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:174)
```

What can be the cause of this problem and how can I fix it? Until now, I've been passing null on the projection arguments, but I don't want to retrieve content I won't be using.

Please ask if you need further informations.

Comment: add BaseColumns._ID to projection array

Comment: aha,  dont override bindView,  use ViewBinder instead

Comment: Can't believe to my eyes. It worked (passed Audio.Artists for convenience) but I can't see how it was possible!
Please, make an answer for your comment explaining the nature of your solution and I'll accept it as soon as possible.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add BaseColumns._ID to projection array. this is the required column when using the CursorAdapter (and i'm assuming from the context that you are using SimpleCursorAdapter)