# Android exception in "requesting column name with table name"

Tags: android, mediastore, android-loadermanager

I've been working on a music player app. In the app, while showing the list of artists, I get a java.lang.exception. Although the app is working and never force closes beacause of this exception. But still I'd like to know the reason behind the exception as it might cause problems later. I've looked at various places for solutions but couldn't find any.

Following is my code for reference:

```
public class ArtistFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

public ArtistFragment(){
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artist_layout, container, false);

    String[] fromColumn = {"MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST"};
    int[] toView = {R.id.songTitle};

    mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.text_item_layout,
            null,
            fromColumn,
            toView,
            0);

    setListAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ArtistActivity.class);
    Cursor cur = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    // I think this might be causing it!
    int artistColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST);
    String artistName = cur.getString(artistColumn);
    i.putExtra("artist_id", id);
    i.putExtra("artist_name", artistName);
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    String[] mProjection =
        {
            MediaStore.Audio.Artists._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST
        };

    String mSelectionClause = null;

    String[] mSelectionArgs = null;

    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            mProjection, mSelectionClause, mSelectionArgs,
            MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST + " ASC");

}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);   //The exception points to this line!
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

}
```

.
And here is the logcat:

```
01-25 15:45:58.027    9719-9719/com.anjani.beatsapp11 E/Cursor﹕ requesting column name with table name -- MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST
java.lang.Exception
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndex(AbstractCursor.java:279)
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:301)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:78)
        at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:333)
        at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:345)
        at com.anjani.beatsapp11.ArtistFragment.onLoadFinished(ArtistFragment.java:88)
        at com.anjani.beatsapp11.ArtistFragment.onLoadFinished(ArtistFragment.java:18)
        at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:483)
        at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:451)
        at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:144)
        at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:109)
        at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:42)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:265)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:92)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

.
.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705356/android-contentresolver-query-throwing-exception-when-passing-a-string-proje

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. The solution given on the above link says to add BaseColumns._ID to projection array. And in my code, I have already done that. Is there something I'm doing wrong?